# getting cell value in gridview

Tags: .net, gridview

I want to get text from literal that is inside  a gridview,

But when i run the program, exception through

Unable to cast object of type System.Web.UI.LiteralControl to type System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl.

**.aspx code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview3" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="qno" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  ShowFooter="true" OnRowCancelingEdit="cancel"   OnRowCommand="create" OnRowDeleting="delete" OnRowEditing="edit" OnRowUpdating="update">

            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selection">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="check1" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="true">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="id7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("assessid") %>' ></asp:Label>

        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qno" Visible="true">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList  AppendDataBoundItems="true"  AutoPostBack="true"     ID="DropDownList1"  runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem ></asp:ListItem>


        </asp:DropDownList>

        </ItemTemplate>



    </asp:TemplateField>




      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="description" Visible="true">
        <ItemTemplate>

         <asp:Literal ID="id6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("description") %>' >
         </asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text='<%#Eval("description") %>' runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>




        </FooterTemplate>


    </asp:TemplateField>











     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="strongagree" Visible="true">
        <EditItemTemplate>
        =

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" Visible="true">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" Text="Edit" CommandName="edit" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>

       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="update" CommandName="update" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>

       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" Text="cancel" CommandName="cancel" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton7" Text="DeleteAll"  CommandName="delete" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>

    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" Visible="true">

        <ItemTemplate>

          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton23" Text="delete" CommandName="delete" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>




    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="bdh" Text="insert " CommandName="insert" runat="server" />

    </FooterTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>







</Columns>






            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />




        </asp:GridView>
```

**code behind**

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       string percentage = ((LiteralControl)e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: i formatted unnecessary code now please review my code

Comment: Have you tried FindControl()? `Control myControl1 = gridview3.FindControl("TextBox1");`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
   string percentage = ((LiteralControl)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
```

to

```
   string percentage = ((DataBoundLiteralControl)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
```

Comment: yes but exception throghs "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl'."

Comment: kindly reply.I am in serious  trouble